# Send object to webservice via kSoap

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

I have a login view, from the view, when user types username, password, I need to send them to a webservice.
The service will then validate the credentials and return an ID.(customerid).

The service needs to be sent an object of 'Credential' class.

The class:

```
public class Credetials {

    private String username;
    private String password;


    public Credetials(){}

    public String getUserName(){
        return this.username;
    }
    public void setUserName(String uname){
        this.username=uname;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password=password;
    }


}
```

The view/activity:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            /* reading username and password*/
            String username=loginname.getText().toString();
            String password=logincode.getText().toString();

            Credetials credentials=new Credetials();
            credentials.setUserName(username);
            credentials.setPassword(password);

            Log.d("username", credentials.getUserName());
            Log.d("password", credentials.getPassword());
            **// here i have proper username and password.**

            new callGetCustomerId().execute(credentials);


        }
    });
class callGetCustomerId extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
        request.addProperty("credentials", params[0]);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            return response.toString();


        }catch(Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Problem:

Now the problem is it always goes to the catch block.
The error is shows somehting like **"Cannot serialize: blah blah..Credentials@413...."**
Can anybody help me out with what am I doing wrong. ??

I have sent single string parameter before which works fine...so I believe my way of sending 'credential' object may be wrong..!!

EDIT:

This is from the web service

```
<xs:complexType name="getCustomerId">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="credetials" type="tns:credentials" minOccurs="0"/>
 </xs:sequence>
```

### EDIT 2:

after trying a lot of things, i have the following response dump.

```
aht responseDump is :
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">     <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
<detail><ns2:exception xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/"     class="java.lang.NullPointerException" 
note="To disable this feature, set   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
<ns2:stackTrace><ns2:frame class="presentation.ws.ElderlyWebServiceImpl"  file="ElderlyWebServiceImpl.java" line="196" method="getNurseId"/>
<ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1173" line="unknown" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl"
```

file="DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="25" method="invoke"/>

so this is what I have as response...Is there something I need to do in the client??
or the service needs to change something??

### EDIT:3

This is how the code looks like now..

### The class

```
public class Credetials implements KvmSerializable{

    /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 920795244030577363L;
    /**
 * 
 */

    private String username;
    private String password;


    public Credetials(){}

    public Credetials(String username,String password){
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
    }
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        Object object = null;
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                object = this.username;
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                object = this.password;
                break;
            }

        }
        return object;
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                propertyInfo.name = "username";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                propertyInfo.name="password";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    public void setProperty(int index, Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0:
        {
            this.username = obj.toString();
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            this.password = obj.toString();
            break;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

### This is the activity:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "mynamespace";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getCustomerId";
private static final String URL = "myurl";


The asynctask
----------------

class callGetCustomerId extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

        Credetials cred=new Credetials("username","password");


        PropertyInfo credPropertyinfo=new PropertyInfo();
        credPropertyinfo.setName("credentials");
        credPropertyinfo.setValue(cred);
        credPropertyinfo.setType(cred.getClass());

        request.addProperty(credPropertyinfo);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, Credetials.class.getSimpleName(), Credetials.class);
     HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
     androidHttpTransport.debug=true;

     try{
            //Log.d("intotry", "inside try");
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            System.out.println("aht requestDump is :"+androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            System.out.println("aht responseDump is :"+androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;



            //return response.toString();
            return "call success";


        }catch(Exception e){
            //return e.getMessage();
            return e.toString();
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //

    }
}
```

### WSDL

```
<xs:complexType name="credentials">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="getCustomerId">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="credetials" type="tns:credentials" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getCustomerIdResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I have written above the output dump.

Comment: You have to serialize your Credential class. Try with implementing Serialize in that class. If you want you can simply do something like "request.addProperty("username", yourUser); request.addProperty("password", yourPass);". According to WSDL contract

Comment: well, I tried public class Credetials implements Serializable()..with no luck. still the same error.

Comment: Wait. Now you can do a request i see. FaultString comes from Server so you can do a connection. The kind of response depends on WS contract and server.

Comment: Ok..so what do I need to try now?? do you wanna see the WSDL? or anything else? i am kind of lost now..

Comment: Exactly. Post WSDL. "request.addProperty(_,_)", method name, namespace, soapAction... depend on WSDL contract

Comment: hi..added the new codes..

Comment: Post the entire xml, not only "types". Like this http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/WWW/webservices/wsdlexample.html

Comment: hi...it works now...it was a ridiculous silly thing.  in the WSDL, it requires an object with the name: 'credetials' and i was sending 'credentials'...Thanks for your help.